# Moving average vs. lagged dependent variable in pass-through regressions

Tags: regression, elasticity

I am estimating a pass-through elasticity of the basic form:

ln(cost) = alpha + ln(price) + controls + error

My issue is that the price charged in period t may be associated with a product purchased at time, say, t-2, so that there is a misalignment between price and cost (and, that misalignment could be between any number of time periods; say, 1 to 5 periods of lag).

I have seen an approach that takes an n-quarter moving average of both cost and price. I'm having a difficult time finding a theoretical basis for this choice. Why do this instead of, say, including several lags of the dependent variable as controls?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!